# Is it possible to count records without trigger?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is it possible to count records and display the key of each record without trigger the data changes?

I can do this

```
firebaseRef.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  //do stuff ...
});
```

but I want to count when even if there are no new value/child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a one time read with `.once()`.

```
firebaseRef.once('value', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.numChildren); // print child count
  snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
    console.log(childSnap.key()); // print each child key
  });
});
```

The callback function will trigger only the initial time, and no for any data changes.